# One to many in Realm for Swift 3.0.2

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

What would be the equivalent to the following Swift 3.0 objects in Realm?

**Regular Swift**

Store Class:

```
import Foundation
class Store{
    var storeName = ""
    var itemList = [Item]()
}
```

Item Class:

```
import Foundation
class Item{ 
    var itemName: String = ""
    var price: Double = 0
}
```

**Realm**

I tried this but I get an error:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Store:Object{
    dynamic var storeName = ""
    dynamic var itemList = List<Item>() // here I get the error
}
```

> Error: Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be
>   represented in Objective-C

Item Class: No error

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item : Object{

    dynamic var itemName: String = ""
    dynamic var price: Double = 0
}
```

Comment: you don't need to declare itemList as dynamic proprtty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example of the [To-Many Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships) section of the Realm Swift documentation, your class should be declared as:

```
class Store: Object {
    dynamic var storeName = ""
    let itemList = List<Item>()
}
```

The `dynamic` modifier cannot be used on `List<T>` properties because it requires that the type of the property be representable in Objective-C, and Swift's generics are not.